# How to access css effect, in jquery function call for a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a **jquery function** which add an **image to body** in the **second code snippet**, using function`$('body').addClass('image');`

i have a **css** which give a **shake effect to the class** **associated** with it, which is done in **class declaration itself**.`<div class="image shake">`

**i want to include this shake effect on calling jquery** function `$('body').addClass('image');`

**How to correct my jquery function soa that it can access that shake effect from css**?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('image');
 $('.image').addClass('shake')
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);

.image {
        background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
}

.shake {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}
.shake:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -ms-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  4% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  8% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  12% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  16% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  28% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  32% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  44% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  48% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  52% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  64% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  66% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  76% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  82% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  84% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  88% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@-ms-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  4% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  8% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  12% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  22% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  24% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  26% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  30% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  32% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  34% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  36% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  42% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  48% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  54% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  58% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  62% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  68% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  70% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  74% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  78% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  80% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  84% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  86% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  90% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  96% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@keyframes shake-base { 0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  4% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  6% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  8% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  12% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  14% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  18% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  32% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  46% { transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  48% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  84% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  92% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  94% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  98% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  



<div class="image shake">
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('image shake');
});
```

```css
.image {
        background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
        
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);


.shake {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}
.shake:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -ms-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-name: shake-base;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  4% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  8% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  12% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  16% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  28% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  32% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  44% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  48% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  52% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  64% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  66% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -webkit-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  76% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  82% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  84% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  88% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -webkit-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -webkit-transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@-ms-keyframes shake-base { 0% { -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  4% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  8% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  12% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  14% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  22% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  24% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  26% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  30% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  32% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  34% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  36% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  42% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  48% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  50% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  54% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  58% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  62% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  68% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  70% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  74% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  78% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  80% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  84% { -ms-transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  86% { -ms-transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { -ms-transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  90% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  92% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  94% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  96% { -ms-transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -ms-transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }

@keyframes shake-base { 0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  4% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  6% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  8% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  12% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  14% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  16% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  18% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  22% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  24% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  26% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  32% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  34% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  36% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  46% { transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  48% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  56% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  64% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  66% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  68% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  72% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  74% { transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  76% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  82% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  84% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  88% { transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  92% { transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  94% { transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); }
  96% { transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg); }
  98% { transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add class `shake` using jquery

Comment: @mohammad how to write that query? please explain

Comment: `$('.image').addClass('shake')`

Comment: @mohammad please see my second code snippet acnt achieve the shake effect using this jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `addClass` calls

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

of simply separate the classes to add by space

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('image shake');
});
```

Comment: please see my second code snippet , i have corrected the jquery but didn't achieve teh shaking effect

Comment: @Jupiter can you create a JSFiddle?